# How to remove the widget controller from desktop

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-environments, plasma

I'd like to know how to hide or remove this square on the top left corner of the desktop. I'm using Kubuntu 16.04.
Here is an image of what I want to remove.
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click somewhere on the desktop, in the context-menu choose `Desktop Settings`. In the Desktop Settings window choose `Tweaks`, uncheck the option `Show the desktop toolbox` and click `Apply`.

[image]